# Section numbering in redefined sections

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, hyperlink

When redefining sections etc. the numbering in the reference is not correct anymore.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

% possibility to have sections etc. be within the margins
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\doxysection}{\@ifstar{\doxysection@star}{\doxysection@nostar}}
\newcommand{\doxysection@star}[1]{\begingroup\sloppy\raggedright\section*{#1}\endgroup}
\newcommand{\doxysection@nostar}[1]{\begingroup\sloppy\raggedright\section{#1}\endgroup}
\makeatother
\usepackage[pdftex,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{ colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, unicode }

\begin{document}
\chapter{Special Commands}
\doxysection{Introduction}
\begin{list}{}
\item \contentsline{section}{\mbox{\hyperlink{commands_cmdaddtogroup}{addtogroup}}}{\ref{commands_cmdaddtogroup}}{}
\item \contentsline{section}{\mbox{\hyperlink{commands_cmdcallgraph}{callgraph}}}{\ref{commands_cmdcallgraph}}{}
\item \contentsline{section}{\mbox{\hyperlink{commands_cmdhidecallgraph}{hidecallgraph}}}{\ref{commands_cmdhidecallgraph}}{}
\end{list}

\hypertarget{commands_cmdaddtogroup}{}\doxysection{addtogroup}\label{commands_cmdaddtogroup}
\hypertarget{commands_cmdcallgraph}{}\section{callgraph}\label{commands_cmdcallgraph}
\hypertarget{commands_cmdhidecallgraph}{}\doxysection{hidecallgraph}\label{commands_cmdhidecallgraph}

\end{document}
```

The output I get is:

[image]

For the purpose of this example I used in the section definitions for the first section a redefined section, for the section section an original section and for the third section again a redefined section.

Here we see that the first reference references to section 1, though this should be 1.2. The second reference is correct but the third reference is again wrong, this should be to 1.4 and not 1.3

It looks like that by redefining the section a "numbering" is not imported / updated inside the new command.

(The tex code is an excerpt from normally automatically generated code from doxygen.)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using grouping around the section title, and this destroys the \label system as label names are stored locally.

Better define your own sectioning command correctly with `\@startsection`:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

% possibility to have sections etc. be within the margins
\makeatletter
\newcommand\doxysection{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\raggedright\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{ colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, unicode }
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Special Commands}
\doxysection{Introduction}
\begin{list}{}
\item \contentsline{section}{\mbox{\hyperlink{commands_cmdaddtogroup}{addtogroup}}}{\ref{commands_cmdaddtogroup}}{}
\item \contentsline{section}{\mbox{\hyperlink{commands_cmdcallgraph}{callgraph}}}{\ref{commands_cmdcallgraph}}{}
\item \contentsline{section}{\mbox{\hyperlink{commands_cmdhidecallgraph}{hidecallgraph}}}{\ref{commands_cmdhidecallgraph}}{}
\end{list}

\hypertarget{commands_cmdaddtogroup}{}\doxysection{addtogroup}\label{commands_cmdaddtogroup}
\hypertarget{commands_cmdcallgraph}{}\section{section}\label{commands_cmdcallgraph}
\hypertarget{commands_cmdhidecallgraph}{}\doxysection{hidecallgraph}\label{commands_cmdhidecallgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The numbers look OK now but the strange thing is that the reference to callgraph is still indented (with just section and with doxysection), this indentation should not be present.

Comment: I tried it in the full package and here I don't seen the extra indentation. The question was about `section` but how would it be for `subsection` (and `subsubsection`...) I tried with `subsection` so the first line reads: `\newcommand\doxysubsection{\@startsection {subsection}{1}{\z@}%` and this looks like to work n a small example but the size of the characters is bigger than with normal `subsection` (Large ?), anything to pay special attention to besides the character size (also for the `paragraph` etc) ? and in a large example I get complaints about the @nostar

Comment: mixing \contentsline with a list environment is rather odd, I thought you were doing it only for the example and so didn't care about the resulting layout. You can find the original settings for \section etc  in book.cls.

Comment: In fact the list is inside a `\begin{multicols}{2}` (and before it the size is set to `\footnotesize`) how should this otherwise be done? Actually I was hoping that there would be an automatic way to grab these value sfrom book.cls (I'm not a fan of copying values).

Comment: But why use a list at all? \contentsline works without it. To change sectioning command you can use packages like sectsty or titlesec. Or switch to a more powerfull class like memoir or scrbook which has suitable hooks.

Comment: The mentioned classes are nice, but in automatically generated tex files it is not so easy to switch, but I'll keep it i mind. I will first look at the problems I encounter with the `nostar` in my appendix F (so after 30 chapters and 5 appendices and still around 20 appendices to go) where it looks like the `\doxysection is not known anymore.

Comment: Problem with the nostar is solved, was in a renewcommand (for sub appendices)